# ReclyclerView and CardView, onclick method perform the action on several CardViews at same time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've got a RecyclerView which populates from an ArrayList. The output is a CardView layout.
In the Cardview, there are 2 buttons amongst other Views. 
They only have to read the current value of a TextView, which by default is 1, and increase or decrease it. 
The Arraylist contains 8 items.

When I run the app the UI works fine. Trouble is when I try to modify the value of the TextView. 
The value is correctly increased and decreased on the CardView I'm working on, but ALSO the value is modified on another CardView. And in that second CardView, modifying its TextView value, also modifies the first one.

So, what am I doing wrong?

This is my Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_rosas extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_rosas,container,false);

    RecyclerView recyclerview_rosas;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adaptador_rv_rosas;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm_rosas;

    List rosas = new ArrayList();

    rosas.add(new Tropa(1,R.drawable.minibarbaro, getResources().getString(R.string.barbaro),7,1));

    recyclerview_rosas = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_tropasRosas);
    recyclerview_rosas.setHasFixedSize(true);

    lm_rosas = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerview_rosas.setLayoutManager(lm_rosas);

    adaptador_rv_rosas = new AdaptadorTropa(rosas);
    recyclerview_rosas.setAdapter(adaptador_rv_rosas);

    return view;
}
```

}

And here the part of code on my Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TropaViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


    viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(items.get(i).getImagen());
    viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(i).getNombre());
    viewHolder.maxnivel.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i).getNivelMax()));
    viewHolder.espacioencamp.setText((String.valueOf(items.get(i).getEspacioEnCamp())));


    final String nombre = items.get(i).getNombre();
    final int maxnivel = items.get(i).getNivelMax();


    viewHolder.nivelmas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String niveltemp = viewHolder.nivel.getText().toString();
            String nivelmaxtemp = viewHolder.maxnivel.getText().toString();

            int nivel = Integer.parseInt(niveltemp);
            int maxxnivel = Integer.parseInt(nivelmaxtemp);
            int nuevonivel = nivel+1   ;

            if (nuevonivel<=maxxnivel) {
                viewHolder.txtv_nivel.setText(String.valueOf(nuevonivel));
            }
        }
    });
```

My OnCreateViewHolder (nothing really happens here):

```
@Override
public TropaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview, viewGroup, false);

    return new TropaViewHolder(v);
}
```

Comment: there are 2 problems with this solution. First, you need to remember the value that is incremented/decremented for each TextView, otherwise, you will always be seeing the default value for TextView when views are recycled. Second, you might want to setup click listeners in onCreateViewHolder to make it more efficient. Seeing your onCreateViewHolder would be very helpful.

Comment: Updated with my onCreateViewHolder, as you can see I just inflate the layout there. Should I write the listeners here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, as mentioned in the comment above, it addresses two problems:
1. positiontoValueMap - saves current value for each position
2. onclicklistener is passed to the ViewHolder in onCreateViewHolder

Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> dataList;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> positionToValueMap = new HashMap<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, null, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view, new OnRecyclerItemClickListener());
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).onRecyclerItemClickListener.updatePosition(position);
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).position.setText("" + position);
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).title.setText(dataList.get(position));

        int valueToDisplay = 1;

        if(positionToValueMap.containsKey(position)) {
            valueToDisplay = positionToValueMap.get(position);
        } else {
            positionToValueMap.put(position, valueToDisplay);
        }

        ((MyViewHolder) holder).valueView.setText("value: " + valueToDisplay);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private OnRecyclerItemClickListener onRecyclerItemClickListener;
        private TextView position;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView valueView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecyclerItemClickListener onRecyclerItemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(onRecyclerItemClickListener);
            this.onRecyclerItemClickListener = onRecyclerItemClickListener;
            this.position = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.position);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.valueView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_view);
        }
    }


    private class OnRecyclerItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int position = -1;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int oldValue = positionToValueMap.get(position); // get current value
            oldValue++; // increment
            positionToValueMap.put(position, oldValue); // save current value
            notifyItemChanged(position); // update clicked view so that it picks up the new saved value from the positionToValueMap in onBindViewHolder
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerView item layout

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/position" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Activity to test it out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getSampleData()));
    }

    private static List<String> getSampleData() {
        List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataList.add("zero");
        dataList.add("one");
        dataList.add("two");
        dataList.add("three");
        dataList.add("four");
        dataList.add("five");
        dataList.add("six");
        dataList.add("seven");
        dataList.add("eight");
        dataList.add("nine");
        dataList.add("ten");
        dataList.add("eleven");
        dataList.add("twelve");
        dataList.add("thirteen");
        dataList.add("fourteen");
        dataList.add("fifteen");
        dataList.add("sixteen");
        dataList.add("seventeen");
        dataList.add("eighteen");
        dataList.add("nineteen");
        dataList.add("twenty");

        return dataList;
    }
}
```

activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer. I'm trying to figure out how to implement your code on mine. What if I want to handle the click event on a specific button and not just the whole RecyclerView item?

Comment: @RaulLopez, you're welcome. All you have to do in that case is change this line itemView.find.setOnClickListener(onRecyclerItemClickListener) in private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Instead of itemView this can be any view that you have inside the recycler view item.

Comment: Thank you, mate!. I've already came up with a solution, I implemented a general onClick listener on the OnRecyclerItemClickListener class and with a switch/case getting the clicked view Id, now I'm able to handle 6 buttons.